# MSBuild not copying files with PublishProfile

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, orchardcms-1.8

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with the full Orchard source code.  When I use "Publish..." on the "Orchard.Web" project in Visual Studio, it correctly publishes the site to the File System destination I've configured into the `.PubXml` file that I used.

However, if I build this site using Jenkins, the files do not get copied to the destination.  I've created a separate PubXml file that is used by Jenkins.

In my Jenkins job, I have two Build steps of interest.  The first uses the `src\Orchard.sln` file with a command line argument of `/p:Configuration=Release`.  This runs correctly, and builds the entire solution.

The second Build step, immediately after, uses the Build File of `src\Orchard.Web\Orchard.Web.csproj` and these command line arguments:

- /p:DeployOnBuild=true
- /p:PublishProfile="D:\workspace\Site\trunk\src\Orchard.Web\Properties\PublishProfiles\Jenkins.pubxml"
- /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
- /p:Configuration=Release
- /p:Platform=AnyCPU
- /v:minimal
- /nologo
- /p:WarningLevel=1

With this, the build and deploy *seems* to work - but doesn't.  Here are some lines from the build output:

```
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Shapes\Scripts\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Shapes\Scripts\Web.config.
(... about 200 more "Auto ConnectionString..." lines...)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

No where does it actually copy the files to the destination defined in the PUBXML file.

In contrast, in Visual Studio, the output looks similar, but transforms only 4 config files and includes lots of "Publishing folder x" lines:

```
(...)
Transformed Modules\SH.GoogleAnalytics\web.config using ....
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Publishing folder /...
Publishing folder bin...
(etc.)
```

(I have installed the latest Windows Azure SDK for .NET on the Jenkins server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same trouble,that work for me:

```html
/t:Rebuild
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:PublishProfile=Jenkins_Publish
/p:Configuration=Release
```

do not use /p:VisualStudioVersion=xxx

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of old, but I actually just set up Orchard to be able to get built via command line and MSBuild. Here is what I did:

/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0;PublishProfile="example-profile";DeployProjA=true;FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v4.5";Configuration=Release;PublishProfileRootFolder=c:\Workspace\src\Orchard.Web\Properties\PublishProfiles;Password=ExamplePass

Since you are using Orchard you want to make sure that only the Orchard.Web project gets published so **do not use DeployOnBuild=true.** This will attempt to deploy every web project in the solution, which is a lot for Orchard. Instead follow the guidelines here to see how to deploy only the web project: http://sedodream.com/2013/03/06/HowToPublishOneWebProjectFromASolution.aspx